# Android Action Bar Custom Up Button behaviour after click

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have a custom up indicator for my action bar. When the user presses it, it changes to a different color, that's working as expected.

There are 2 problems:

1) When the user presses on the up indicator and holds down and moves off of the up indicator touch area. The up indicator changes colors back to its default faster than the title area changes colors back to its default.

2) When the user actually clicks (press down and release up) and when the next activity is loading, the up indicator is back in its default state, while the title area is in its pressed state. I need both of them to be the same state, it looks bad when they aren't in agreement.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_up_indicator_default"/>
```